# WCF service not working in IIS host but working in development server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, iis

I'm developing in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, Webforms.
Development environment is Windows8.1, and IIS version is 8.5.

1) During debugging (with the development server ) , it is displayed as "Connection Successful!!" when you press the "LogInMe" button . 
However, deploying in the folder that I specify in IIS ,failed and called "Error!!".
(The permissions of the folder is Everyone. And firewall function of Windows is invalidated.)

2) Just for added information…
After deploying in IIS folder, "http: //localhost/TEST/TEST.aspx " appears as expected page.
But in "http: //localhost/TEST/TESTWCF.SVC", the message shows ,"the end point can not be found .”

How can I fix the codes? Or are there a place to review the IIS settings?

Below is a part of Web.config

```html
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DaishinWCFAspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
          multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
          <service name="Shop.DaishinWCF">

            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="DaishinWCFAspNetAjaxBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Shop.DaishinWCF" />

          </service>
        </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Below is View Code of TESTWCF.svc.vb

```html
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Web.Providers.Entities
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()> _
        <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Function fnVerifyID(ByVal ID As String, ByVal PASS As String)

End Interface
<DataContract()> _
Public Class csVerifyID
    Dim sID As String
    Dim iFlg As Integer
    Dim sName As String


    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return sName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            sName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")> _
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class DaishinWCF


    <WebGet()>
    Public Function fnVerifyID(ByVal ID As String, ByVal PASS As String)

        Dim Hyouji As String = CStr(ID) & CStr(PASS)

        Dim objVeryfyID As New csVerifyID

        objVeryfyID.Name = "Connection Succeeded!!"

        Dim person As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objVeryfyID)

        Return person

    End Function


End Class
```

Below is Test.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Mobile.Master" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Shop.Daishin" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<title>Test Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>--%>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jCarousel.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#LogInMe').click(function () {


            var UserName = $('#txtUserName').val()
            var Password = $('#txtPassword').val() 
            var Para = { ID: $('#txtUserName').val(), PASS: $('#txtPassword').val() };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/TestWCF.svc/fnVerifyID', 
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json', 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                traditional: true,
                data: Para ,

                success: function (response) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(response.d);            
                        alert(obj.Name)
                }, 

                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    alert('Connection Error!!');

                } 
            });

        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="p-listview-thumbnail" >

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
           <h1></h1>
            <a href="#Family" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d" >Options</a>   
            <input type="text" id="txtUserName" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="passwordinput" id="txtPassword"  placeholder="Password" value=""  />
            <a href="javascript:Authenticate();" id="LogInMe" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right">Log Me In!</a>
             <label for="basic_name" id="lblMessage"></label>            
        </div>

</body>
</html>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: WCF is not enabled by default. Check on the target machine to make sure it is enabled and registered on IIS correctly.